# Filter array of object based on multiple conditions in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I wanna filter person list according to city job age gender how can I filter based on five conditions in react, I used filter chaning but it did not work for me .in useEffect hook I filter  individual condition and then i used chaning filter but it seems I should  respectively filtered

briefly i wanna filtered persons according to five conditions to handle this scenario I used useEffect hook and I used filter method to each condition but I don't know how they can work together

```
  const [persons, setPersons] = useState([
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "mosh",
      gender: "0",
      city: "London",
      category: "frontend",
      age: 27,
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "saheb",
      gender: "1",
      city: "Paris",
      category: "backend",
      age: 32,
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: "vahid",
      gender: "0",
      city: "Rome",
      category: "frontend",
      age: 43,
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      name: "kianosh",
      gender: "1",
      city: "London",
      category: "designer",
      age: 29,
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      name: "milad",
      gender: "0",
      city: "Paris",
      category: "designer",
      age: 41,
    },
    {
      id: 6,
      name: "parviz",
      gender: "1",
      city: "Rome",
      category: "designer",
      age: 56,
    },
    {
      id: 7,
      name: "farid",
      gender: "0",
      city: "London",
      category: "frontend",
      age: 37,
    },
    {
      id: 8,
      name: "rezgar",
      gender: "1",
      city: "Rome",
      category: "backend",
      age: 29,
    },
    {
      id: 9,
      name: "ali",
      gender: "0",
      city: "Paris",
      category: "backend",
      age: 48,
    },
  ]);
  const [filteredPersons, setFilteredPersons] = useState([]);
  const [checkedValue, setCheckedValue] = useState([]);
  const [select, setSelect] = useState("all");
  const [gender, setGender] = useState("");
  const [range, setRange] = useState(100);
  const [max, setMax] = useState(null);
  const [search, setSearch] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    const maximum = Math.max(...persons.map((item) => item.age));
    setMax(maximum);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useeffect runs");
    const oldPersons = [...persons];
    const filteredCity = (person) => {
      if (checkedValue.includes(person.city)) {
        return person;
      }
      return null;
    };
    const filteredAge = (person) => {
      return person.age < range;
    };
    const filteredGender = (person) => {
      return person.gender == gender;
    };
    const filteredSelect = (person) => {
      if (select === "all") {
        return person;
      } else {
        return person.category == select;
      }
    };

    const filteredAllPersons = oldPersons
      .filter(filteredGender)
      .filter(filteredAge)
      .filter(filteredSelect)
      ?.filter(filteredCity)
    setFilteredPersons(filteredAllPersons);
  }, [checkedValue, select, gender, range, search]);
```

Comment: What do you mean it didn't work for you? What do you expect to happen and what happens instead?

Comment: when i checked city and console loged filteredAllPersons that give me empty array and I don't know how filter persons according to these conditions such as city and job and gender

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that you are applying all of your filters instead of just ones that are defined. And also you also should just return false from your filters if they are defined, that is the only way to run through all of them. So your code should look something like this

```
const filteredAllPersons = oldPersons.filter(person => {
  if (genderFilter && person.gender !== genderFilter) {
    return false
  }
  // apply all other filters the same as above

  // Finally return true because record has satisfied all conditions
  return true
})
```

Comment: @AdibSadeghi this one or the one you selected as correct answer(from Javad)

Comment: your answer is correct i selected your answer

Answer (score 3):

You can only handle it through one filter() method

```
useEffect(() => {
    const oldPersons = [...persons];

    const filteredAllPersons = oldPersons.filter(person => {
        if(!checkedValue.includes(person.city)) return false;

        if(person.age >= range) return false;

        if(person.gender !== gender) return false;

        if (select === "all") return person;

        return person.category === select;
    })

    setFilteredPersons(filteredAllPersons);
}, [persons, checkedValue, select, gender, range]);
```

in return

```
return filteredPersons.length > 0 && <div>{console.log(filteredPersons)}</div>
```

Comment: thanks javad for your answer but for the first time when I console log filtered persons that give me empty array

Comment: You're welcome, so you need to wait for setting state through handling empty state, I updated my answer